# How to handle performance of parallel CRUD in single table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, orm, parallel-processing, sql-server-2012

I have a table named "Daily Result" that contain calculated information of all users in my application.this info are generated after running a calc method for each user.this method use data of multi relative table.

in my app after some actions I need to reCalculate info of "DailyResult" table for one or all users.

in this situation I will create threads to do calc.but my problem is when call calc method for multi user the threads will wait for resource table ("DailyResult") to release.and that method take time.

we use MVC 3, Sql server Enterprise 2012 64 bit, Dapper ORM for insert-delete-update info.

we use nhibrenate already but have to replace it with dapper.it is better but for parallel user over 2000 it take times to insert-delete-update info in Dailyresult table.

what is best solution for handle this issue,to ham maximum performance.what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you what to access the table during the "reCalculate" phase? So - if you can edit the query which you use to obtain data from the table in your app, add "set transaction isolation  level read uncommitted;" at the beginning